# Removing property from object in array if value is 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I remove a property from an object if its value is zero?

```
var row = [{
  2013: "0", 
  2014: "0",       
  2015: "95163",
  carseries: "Sindelfingen"
},{
  2013: "0", 
  2014: "38954", 
  2015: "0", 
  2016: "0", 
  carseries: "Bremen"
}];
```

Output should look like this:

```
var row = [{
  2015: "95163",
  carseries: "Sindelfingen"
},{
  2014: "38954",  
  carseries: "Bremen"
}];
```

Comment: Post your code, what have you tried?

Comment: 1. [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). 2. *Nothing* about this is JSON. What you have is simply an array of objects. I amended the title/description/tags to reflect this 3. jQuery is primarily for amending the DOM, so is not needed for changing a data structure.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use combination of array iterators: [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
function clean(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj) // get own keys
               .filter(function(key) {  // keep non '0' values
                 return obj[key] !== '0'
               })
              .reduce(function(out, key) { // recreate object using filtered keys
                 out[key] = obj[key]

                 return out
              }, {})
}

var row = [{
  2013: "0",
  2014: "0",
  2015: "95163",
  carseries: "Sindelfingen"
}, {
  2013: "0",
  2014: "38954",
  2015: "0",
  2016: "0",
  carseries: "Bremen"
}];

// apply clean function to each element of initial array
console.log(row.map(clean))
```

Answer (score 1):

This works too :

```
row.forEach( // loop through your array 
    function(element) {
        for (key in element) { // for every key in the current object
            if (element[key] === '0') { // if it's valued to '0'
                delete element[key]; // remove it from the object
            }
        }
    }

);
```

Comment: I tested the performance https://jsperf.com/remove-property-array-iterator-vs-loop and your algorithm seem faster than @Yury Tarabanko one, it's easier to understand too.

Answer (score 0):

to delete an item from an object you can use CANCEL and you can get the output you want by using two FOR loops =)

```js
var row = [{
  2013: "0", 
  2014: "0",       
  2015: "95163",
  carseries: "Sindelfingen"
},{
  2013: "0", 
  2014: "38954", 
  2015: "0", 
  2016: "0", 
  carseries: "Bremen"
}];

for(var i = 0; row[i]; i++){
  for(var key in row[i]) {
    if(row[i][key] === "0") delete row[i][key];
  }
}

console.log(row);
```